# Magento API error while creating gost account

Tags: magento2, error, api

When i'm pasing `$customerObject->newsletter  = $wantToSubscribe;` in magento API in log there is error LogicException: Property "Newsletter" does not have corresponding setter in class

```
public static function createGhostCustomer($email,$websiteId,$wantToSubscribe)
{
    self::auth();

    $websiteData = self::extractWebsiteAndStore();
    //print_r($websiteData);exit;

    if(!isset($websiteData[$websiteId]))
    {
        throw new Exception('Website does not exists');
    }

    $customerObject = new \stdClass();
    $customerObject->group_id   = 1; //Retail
    $customerObject->email      = $email;
    $nameToken = explode('@',$email);
    $customerObject->firstname  = '.';
    $customerObject->lastname   = '.';
    $customerObject->customAttributes[] = ['attributeCode'=>'contact_preference','value'=>"50"];
    $customerObject->customAttributes[] = ['attributeCode'=>'created_from_track','value'=>"53"];

// New object
      $customerObject->newsletter  = $wantToSubscribe;  
//
    $customerObject->store_id = $websiteData[$websiteId]['store_id'];
    $customerObject->website_id = $websiteData[$websiteId]['website_id'];

    $body = json_encode(['customer'=>$customerObject]);
    $result = self::call('POST',self::$_url.'V1/customers',$body);

    return json_decode($result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is because there is no setNewsLetter() method declared in Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface. as the endpoint which you are using to create customer account accept and returns CustomerInterface. Below you can see xml and interface code.

```
<route url="/V1/customers" method="POST">
    <service class="Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface" method="createAccount"/>
    <resources>
        <resource ref="anonymous"/>
    </resources>
</route>

/**
 * Create customer account. Perform necessary business operations like sending email.
 *
 * @param \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface $customer
 * @param string $password
 * @param string $redirectUrl
 * @return \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface
 * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
 */
public function createAccount(
    \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface $customer,
    $password = null,
    $redirectUrl = ''
);
```

Comment: Did my answer help you?